# Emacs - Require All Files In a Directory

Tags: emacs, directory, elisp, require

I am familiar with `load-path` and `require`, but I was wondering if I can consolidate the multiple `require` statements in my **init.el** into some kind of loop, ultimately doing something like `require`-ing all the files in a given directory.

Is there any way to do this?  Or should I keep it as it is, with multiple `require` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Drew that you want to use `load` in this situation. This function is based on Drew's code, with a few tweaks to avoid re-loading a library when both .el and .elc versions are present.

```el
(defun my-load-all-in-directory (dir)
  "`load' all elisp libraries in directory DIR which are not already loaded."
  (interactive "D")
  (let ((libraries-loaded (mapcar #'file-name-sans-extension
                                  (delq nil (mapcar #'car load-history)))))
    (dolist (file (directory-files dir t ".+\\.elc?$"))
      (let ((library (file-name-sans-extension file)))
        (unless (member library libraries-loaded)
          (load library nil t)
          (push library libraries-loaded))))))
```

Comment: I would use "load", but doing so makes Emacs start up differently than using "require".  Specifically, rather than having all of my customizations applied at once, there are numerous quick visual changes (such as changing the modeline color, etc.) that occur with "load" that don't happen with "require".  Is there a hook I can put this in that will apply the file contents with less visual surprise?

Comment: `require` is just a wrapper around `load`. There should be no difference between the two, unless you `load` a library twice, and this function ought to prevent that from happening. The only other point of difference for this question might be the order in which you load the directory files. You could try changing `(directory-files dir t ".+\\.elc?$" t)` to `(directory-files dir t ".+\\.elc?$")` (i.e. removing the final argument) which will give you the same sorting as in the accepted answer.

Comment: I actually found why it was looking different myself.  It turns out the load messages were making the loading proccess itself look asynchronous, so I passed an argument to `load` disabling it.  Thanks!

Comment: Good spotting; `require`'s C code does indeed call `load` with `NOMESSAGE` set to `t`. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for providing the above function -- it is extremely useful.  Could you please explain the usage of mapcar in (mapcar #'file-name-sans-extension (delq nil (mapcar #'car load-history)) and particularly the significance of the "#".

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35988 and others discuss the differences between `#'` and `'` (shorthand for `(function ...)` and `(quote ...)` respectively, but in this case there is no *need* to use the sharp quotes; a plain quote would have given exactly the same result.

Comment: ...and if you're still unsure what that form does, try evaluating each of the following in turn in your `*scratch*` buffer: `load-history`, `(mapcar #'car load-history)`, `(mapcar #'file-name-sans-extension (delq nil (mapcar #'car load-history)))`

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```lisp
(mapc (lambda (name)
        (require (intern (file-name-sans-extension name))))
      (directory-files ".emacs.d" nil "\\.el$"))
```

Explanation:

1. retrieve the list of elisp files using `directory-files`
2. remove extension using `file-name-sans-extension`
3. get the symbol associated to the file base name using `intern`, and `require` it

Answer (score 3):

```
(let ((loaded  (mapcar #'car load-history)))
  (dolist (file  (directory-files "~/.emacs.d" t ".+\\.elc?$"))
    (unless (catch 'foo
              (dolist (done  loaded)
                (when (equal file done) (throw 'foo t)))
              nil)
      (load (file-name-sans-extension file))
      (push file loaded))))
```

- Use `load`, not `require`, since the feature name (from `provide`) is not necessarily the same as the base name of the file.  Or the file might not even `provide` a feature.
- Load a file only if it has not yet been loaded (or you have already tried to load it).